# Cycling through a string, and separate by words?

Tags: c

I'm trying to reverse a given string, and I've already fully reversed it, but now I need to reverse each word by itself so that they're readable.

e.g. input: `Reverse this string.`

current output: `.gnirts siht esreveR`

desired output: `string. this Reverse`

Is there some way I can run my string reversing function again on each particular word?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor I want to cycle through the string with a for loop and when it reaches non-whitespace text, store that character and every character after until the next whitespace.  Then I can reverse it and place it in in a new string, and repeat this with the other words.  I don't know how to have it stop when it reaches a non-whitespace character or when it reaches a whitespace character though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reverse function which accepts start and end offsets for the string:

```
void rstr(char *s, int start, int end) {
  /* ... */
}

int main(){
  char str[] = "this is a sentence of words";
  int i, p;
  rstr(str, 0, strlen(str));
  for (p = i = 0; i <= strlen(str); i++) {
    if (str[i] == ' '  || i == strlen(str)) {
      rstr(str, p, i); 
      p = i + 1;
    }   
  }
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

run your reverse alroithm again on each of the results of strtok

```
    char* token = strtok(str, ' ');

    while (token)
    {
       reversedWord = YourReverseAlgorithm(token);
        token = strtok(0, ' ');
    }
```

each call to strtok gives you the token of the original string up to the delimitting character, which in your case is ' '. Simple conscise, and works.